# CMake with gRPC cannot find gRPCTargets.cmake

Tags: cmake, grpc

I am having issues building the `grpc` `cpp` `helloworld` example with `cmake`.
I built and installed `grpc` with `cmake` initially, and then with `make` directly.

I have found [this](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/11378) issue raised by someone else in the past, which was closed as resolved.
It does not appear to be resolved and I opened a new [issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/19873) for it, but I feel it will be some time until I get some help, so here I am.

The OP of the original issue offers a workaround with his [FindGRPC](https://github.com/zhengwx11/FindGRPC) cmake module, but I am not sure how is this suppose to help if `gRPCTargets.cmake` is still missing.
I dropped `FindGRPC.cmake` inside my cmake modules path, but nothing changes.

The error is this:

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/lib/cmake/grpc/gRPCConfig.cmake:8 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    /usr/local/lib/cmake/grpc/gRPCTargets.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:73 (find_package)


-- Using gRPC 1.20.0
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred
```

I want to be able to use `grpc` from my cmake projects without much hassle (using `find_package(gRPC CONFIG REQUIRED)`)

*EDIT:*

When running `cmake` on `grpc` I get this error:

```
gRPC_INSTALL will be forced to FALSE because gRPC_ZLIB_PROVIDER is "module"
```

This is printed from `zlib.cmake`:

```
message(WARNING "gRPC_INSTALL will be forced to FALSE because gRPC_ZLIB_PROVIDER is \"module\"")
```

Apparently all the providers must be `"package"` as mentioned in `grpc`'s `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(gRPC_INSTALL ${gRPC_INSTALL_default} CACHE BOOL
    "Generate installation target: gRPC_ZLIB_PROVIDER, gRPC_CARES_PROVIDER, gRPC_SSL_PROVIDER and gRPC_PROTOBUF_PROVIDER must all be \"package\"")
```

I am not sure why `zlib` is a module here though, or how to make it a package.
Do I need to somehow specify to `cmake` to use the installed zlib instead of the submodule one?

Comment: Do you still have the grpc build directory? What is the value of gRPC_INSTALL in CMakeCache.txt?

Comment: ... And when you ran `cmake` in the gRPC dir, did it say something about "gRPC_INSTALL will be forced to FALSE" ?

Comment: `gRPC_INSTALL:BOOL=ON` I don't remember seeing something about it being forced to false.

Comment: if GRPC_INSTALL was still true at the end of CMakeLists.txt, the generated `cmake_install.cmake` should contain instructions to install `gRPCTargets.cmake`. Does it?

Comment: It does not! It only has details about `gRPCConfig.cmake` and `gRPCConfigVersion.cmake`.

Comment: And indeed `gRPCConfig.cmake` and `gRPCConfigVersion.cmake` are deployed, but `gRPCConfig.cmake` referes to `gRPCTargets.cmake` which is not there.

Comment: Yes, this is direct evidence that gRPC_INSTALL became false at some point in the cmake process, and that *must* be accompanied by a warning print. Add a `message("gRPC_INSTALL is now ${gRPC_INSTALL}")` statement right before it is set to FALSE in CMakeLists.txt (4 possible places, if I recall correctly)

Comment: You were right, I get that message: ` gRPC_INSTALL will be forced to FALSE because gRPC_ZLIB_PROVIDER is "module"`

Comment: Try the solution in https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/13841#issuecomment-355510534 , if you hadn't already found it yourself. If that works I will formulate an answer so other people can find it.

Comment: This did the job, I can't believe I just had to define the providers as `package` myself. Why wouldn't this be the default if it does not work to install with `module`. It could look for the installed `package`s and default to `module` just if it does not find them. Anyway... please post your answer. Thank you.

Comment: I think the answer will be "patches welcome" ;) Defaulting to "module" ensures you know what you are building against, though. That is a good property for many users :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The cause of this problem is explained at https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/13841:

> Because of some limitations of our current CMakeLists.txt, the install targets (see gRPC_INSTALL option) will only be generated if you are building using a pre-installed version of our dependencies (gRPC_CARES_PROVIDER in your case needs to be set to package).
>
> The warning you saw "gRPC_INSTALL will be forced to FALSE because gRPC_CARES_PROVIDER" is "module" basically tells you that even though gRPC_INSTALL was set to ON by you, we're setting it back to OFF because your gRPC_CARES_PROVIDER is set to use c-ares from git submodule (which wouldn't work well with the current CMakeLists.txt) - so you shouldn't expect anything to be installed (not even grpc_cpp_plugin.

To fix this issue, you should carefully look at the output when invoking `cmake`. For every `gRPC_*_PROVIDER` that is reported as "module", you should force it to "package" with `-DgRPC_CARES_PROVIDER=package` (make sure to install the package as well, then!)

Or just force everything with the command-line linked in the issue:

```
 cmake -DgRPC_INSTALL=ON -DgRPC_BUILD_TESTS=OFF -DgRPC_PROTOBUF_PROVIDER=package -DgRPC_ZLIB_PROVIDER=package -DgRPC_CARES_PROVIDER=package -DgRPC_SSL_PROVIDER=package -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ../..
```